# How do I upload a file from iOS to my website?

Tags: javascript, ios, upload, web, zk

I have a website that receives files from the user, using the "Choose file" interface for the OS they're on. This worked for me on Windows, Mac and Linux, but not on iOS. When I click the button that should load the interface, nothing happens. I guess I have to do it in a specific way for iOS. We're using the ZK framework to develop the website, but if you know how to do the upload in some other way, please tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to iOS version 5.X, there is no possibility to upload a file via an html input tag. You would have to create a native App based on PhoneGap/Cordova to have the ability to create images/videos to be uploaded. But that's quite some effort to do. You should definitely think about the following option:

Since iOS version 6.0 Apple has added support for input type file elements. See more details on that here: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers

This way seems to be appropriate, since the adoption rate of iOS 6 is quite high right now (nearly 80%): http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/